# duplicate record while importing and inserting csv file data into salesforce via vf page

Tags: apex

I have a weird requirement now. In the below pic column A, B, C needs to go to object Account and column D should go to another object Type__c and Type__c should be a child of Account.

Requirement is

Current code is working

If Id's are same then only one record is getting created in Account object and AccountNumber is getting inserted as CC978213;CD355119-A.

Where i am stuck is

When Id's are same one record is getting created in Account simulataneoulsy 1 record should get created in Type__c object if Type is having same value for that ID.And if column A, B , C are same but D is different, one record should get created for Account having one account number and 2 record should get crated in Type__c object .

[image]

```
   public class importDataFromCSVController {
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
public string csvAsString{get;set;}
public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
public List<account> acclist{get;set;}
    public map<string, string> csvmap = new map<string, string>();
    public map<string, Account> accmap = new map<string, Account>();
    List<Type__c> typeList = new List<Type__c>();
  public importDataFromCSVController(){
    csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    acclist = New List<Account>(); 
  }

  public void importCSVFile(){
       try{
           csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
           csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 


      for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){

           string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
                if(csvmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0])){
           csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvmap.get(csvRecordData[0])+','+csvRecordData[2]);
               }
                else{
                csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvRecordData[2]) ;
                    }
            }

           system.debug('@@@@@@'+ csvmap);
  /*  for(string str : csvmap.keyset())
     {
       Account accObj = new Account() ;

           accObj.name = str ;             
           accObj.test__c= csvmap.get(str);                                                                      
           acclist.add(accObj); 

      }   

        insert acclist;*/
        for(string str : csvmap.keyset())
{
    Account accObj = new Account() ;
    accObj.name = str ;             
    accObj.test__c= csvmap.get(str);                                                                      
    accmap.put(str , accObj); 
}

insert accmap.values();

Map<Id, set<string>> typeAccMap = new Map<Id, set<string>>();
for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
    string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
    if(accmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0])){
        Account acc = accmap.get(csvRecordData[0]);
        if(typeAccMap.containsKey(acc.id))
        {
            Set<String> typeSet = typeAccMap.get(acc.id);
            if(! typeSet.contains(csvRecordData[3]))
            system.debug('@@@@@' + typeSet);
            system.debug('@@@@@' + csvRecordData[3]);
            {
                Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[3], Account__c = acc.id); 
                typeList.add(t);
               // typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]).add(csvRecordData[3]));
Set<string> tmpSet = typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]);
tmpSet.add(Id.valueOf(csvRecordData[3]));
typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], tmpSet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
              Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[3], Account__c = acc.id); 
              typeList.add(t);
              typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], new Set<String>{csvRecordData[3]});
        }

       }
upsert typeList;
       }
       }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct');
            ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
        }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Here type is child of Account?

Comment: yes type is a child of account

Comment: check my answer if it works for you.

Comment: check your updated code.

Comment: @tushar... i am crying now.. again error..Compile Error: Incompatible value type Boolean for Map<Id,Set<String>> at line 65 column 17

Comment: @Please share exact CSV format and highlight the error line as well because this code looks ok to me.

Comment: @tushar.. i hv highlighted the line where i am getting error..i dont know how to upload the csv file here.. I have posted an image here above..

Comment: @tushar... if i comment this two lines..typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], new Set<String>{csvRecordData[3]}); & typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]).add(csvRecordData[3]));...i am able to save the class.. But in the above pic the last two records Type column is not getting inserted...on the page i am getting error like ..Record ID: cannot specify Id in an insert call ...

Comment: @tushar...typeAccMap -- is always null .. so typeAccMap.containsKey(acc.id)  will be alsways false.. is this right?

Comment: TypeMap is not null othwise you will get null pointer exception. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @tushar ..still i am getting the same error..i hv updated my code above where i am not getting the error. But the code is creating two records for the first two rows in the pic above..

Comment: firat I don't see the changes which I mentioned. You are using account id in inserr call which will give you exception. Remove that and check my answer. I tested same code and it is working fine for me. Also (Id.valueOf(csvRecordData[3])); in column 4 you have string so this line must give exception but you are saying it is working. I doubt this. Do all steps I have mentioned and it Will work for you.

Comment: Hi Tushar.. i have got confused with the codes.. Can u plz update my code with ur code.. So that i can test it...

Comment: @tushar.. Can u plzz update my code.. ..

Comment: @tushar.. i if i check ur below code line ... Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[2], AccountId__c = acc.id); ..u r also passing account id in insert call.. Plzz correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: @tushar... can u plz check...

Comment: I have already told you remove Id column from your CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You need another map and a loop to complete this step

```
public map<string, Account> accmap = new map<string, Account>();
List<Type__c> typeList = new List<Type__c>();
for(string str : csvmap.keyset())
{
    Account accObj = new Account() ;
    accObj.name = str ;             
    accObj.accountnumber = csvmap.get(str);                                                                      
    accmap.put(str , accObj); 
}

insert accmap.values();

//second loop
Map<Id, set<string>> typeAccMap = new Map<Id, set<string>>();
for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
    string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
    if(accmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0])){
        Account acc = accmap.get(csvRecordData[0]);
        if(typeAccMap.containsKey(acc.id))
        {
            Set<String> typeSet = typeAccMap.get(acc.id);
            if(! typeSet.contains(csvRecordData[2]))
            {
                Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[2], AccountId__c = acc.id); 
                typeList.add(t);
                typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]).add(csvRecordData[2]));
            }
        }
        else
        {
              Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[3], AccountId__c = acc.id); 
              typeList.add(t);
              typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], new Set<String>{csvRecordData[2]});
        }

       }
insert typeList;
```

**PS:** I am not sure about the csv column number so you can handle that also if some column contains blank you need to handle that as well.

Remove the ID column from csv.

Comment: Hi tushar , i am getting error .. Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Map<String,Account>].add(String, Account) at line 38 column 12

Comment: @learnjqueery you need to do `accmap.put(str , accObj); ` check my answer.

Comment: tushar.. one record is coming as Account Number :
Customer - Channel ,Customer - Channel.. this should be Account Number 
Customer - Channel . and in this Type__c is haing two records Customer - Channel (2 times) which should be 1 time..

Comment: @learnjqueery can you please specify CSV column order csvRecordData[0])+','+csvRecordData[3] because 0 index for ID and we can't specify Id in insert call.

Comment: The above pic is from the csv file.. Its in that order..

Comment: you can take id as a refernece.. i will try to alter it later..

Comment: @learnjqueery check my updated answer. Your duplicate type error will be solved. For account name I don't touch that part in my code so I think you have done some mistake while copy pasting and changing index in your code.

Comment: @tushar..in this line ..                accmap.put(csvRecordData[0], accmap.get(csvRecordData[0]).add(csvRecordData[3]));.. should we use .add here..its throwing error

Comment: its throwing error ..Incompatible value type Set<String> for Map<String,Account> in line no 63.. i hv updated my code above

Comment: @learnjqueery there was some type in my code . Check now.

Comment: getting error again..Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Account].add(String) at line 65 column 79.. am i doing anything wrong...i hv updated my current code..